# How do I make a custom adapter work for a class in Android?

Tags: java, android

Basically, I'm just trying to make a list with two textviews (a string and an int) with the string coming from an `EditText`, and one button.

I created a custom adapter and also an xml file for the list item. I've been stuck on this problem for a few days.

When I run it the app crashes and the compiler is saying (These are the important things I pulled out)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at com.example.avengerlol.onmyown.MainActivity.onAddItem(MainActivity.java:63)
```

Here's what I have so far:

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public ArrayList<SuperMan> list;
public class SuperMan {
    public int counter = 0;
    public String theName;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<SuperMan> list = new ArrayList<SuperMan>();

    MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(list, this);

    ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.the_whole_list);
    lView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void onAddItem (View v)
{
    EditText etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addItemText);
    SuperMan letsGo = new SuperMan();
    letsGo.theName = etNewItem.getText().toString();

    list.add(letsGo);
    etNewItem.setText("");

}
}
```

My custom adapter class

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
private ArrayList<MainActivity.SuperMan> list = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<MainActivity.SuperMan> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.superman_list, null);
    }

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list

    TextView listItemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    TextView listItemCounter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemCounter);
    Button increaseButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.increaseButton);


    return view;
}


}
```

My main xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"                                               
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
 tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addItemText"
    android:id="@+id/the_whole_list"
    />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addItemText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:hint="Enter a new item"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAddItem"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnAddItem"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Item"
    android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="onAddItem"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My list item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemName"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemCounter"

    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/increaseButton"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a NullPointerException because your list isn't initialized.
I think your are trying it inside your onCreate method.

```
ArrayList<SuperMan> list = new ArrayList<SuperMan>();
```

What happens is that you create an ArrayList named list which is only visible inside your onCreate method. This initilization doesnt affect your member variable. The variable `list` in onCreate hides `list` of your class.
Replacing this line with

```
list = new ArrayList<SuperMan>();
```

will initialize your member and the NPE is gone.

Comment: Thank you!! Would you have any idea how to go about getting a list with a string, int, and button for each item?

Comment: @quickdash Take a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

**NullPointerException** is because you are creating a new local variable in the function `onCreate()`. Instead you have to just initialize the class member variable `list` as follows:

```
list = new ArrayList<SuperMan>();
```

instead of the

```
ArrayList<SuperMan> list = new ArrayList<SuperMan>();
```

What is actually happening here is that you are trying to create a new `list` and perform operations on that local variable that has scope within the method itself. Once the control is returned from the `onCreate()` method the changes aren't effecting the class member variable `list`.

Next when you write this line in `onAddItem()` method:

```
list.add(letsGo);
```

The `add()` is called on a `null` object itself thus causing the **NullPointerException**.